# How to open child node in JsTree when child nodes do not exist until parent is expanded?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have a parent with multiple children nodes. The problem is if I want to open a specific node I call `$("#jstree").jstree("open_node", $('#node_27'));`. The problem is that the parent node is not open so the `$('#node_27')` returns an empty array.

If I have the child ID how can I open it when they are not added to the DOM until the parent is opened?

Comment: first expand parent and then open child

Comment: I don't know the parent ID I only have the child ID. This is even more complex when you are talking about 4 or more parents to get the child

Comment: if you know the root id you can expand all and then open the child node you want and close the others

Comment: I have a tree that has X nodes that can be expanded and X that can not be. Within the X that can be expanded there are Y numbers of items within it that may or may not be expandable and this repeats as the entire tree is dynamic. The only ID I know is the ID of the entire tree and the ID the of specific element I am wanting to open to. So I will know the entire tree is #JSTree and I want node50 or something similar to that

Comment: and $("#jstree").jstree("open_node", 'node_27'); does not work?

Comment: That is correct, it displays `false` in the console

Comment: could you make a small fiddle replicating your problem? Haven´t used the library in a few years

Comment: I can do better then that. If you go to https://www.jstree.com/ and colapse the 'Another Node' node in the first little demo and run `$("#jstree1").jstree("open_node", 'j1_5');` in your console it will reproduce the same error. If you watch the HTML of the `li` element that expands you will notice that the markup for the child node does not exist until the parent is expanded.

Comment: I think you want to use _open_to instead of open_node

Comment: It appears that _open_to is a private method and can not be called. I tried ---`$("#jstree1").jstree("_open_to ", 'j1_5');`---and it returned the tree but did not open the node, were you able to get it working? Trailing space messed this up, this worked

Comment: you have a whitespace after your to

Comment: Thanks! If you want to make an official answer Ill mark it for ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently if you want to "deep open" a node, you would need to use

```
$("#jstree1").jstree("open_node", ['rootId','childId','childChildId','yourNodeId']);
```

However, there is a method called _open_to that already does that automatically, so you can do:

```
$("#jstree1").jstree("_open_to", 'yourNodeId'); //j1_5 in your case
```

And it will open whatever it needs to so as to reach the node you want

Answer (score 1):

The `_open_to` method is a private one and is not supposed to be used directly. Though working right now it may change in the future, e.g. when the jsTree author decides to change the internal mechanics of his library.

To open parents down to the node you can simply use

```
$('#jstree1').jstree('select_node', 'node_27' );
```

As a bonus you will get the target node selected.

Comment: Worth noting - I found this also fires the associated event for the node.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ajax to populate tree, there is lazy loading of child nodes. You must first use 'load_node' to load parent node and then use 'select_node' for children node.

```
$('#jstree').on('refresh.jstree', function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree(true).load_node('parent-id', function () {
        $('#jstree').jstree().deselect_all();
        $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child-id');
    });
});
$('#jstree').jstree(true).refresh(false, false);
```